# How to predict image from a pre-trained model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I want to predict my image from a pre-trained keras xception image model. I have written some code but I get errros. The code is below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Load the pre-trained Xception model to be used as the base encoder.
xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)
# Set the trainability of the base encoder.
for layer in xception.layers:
 layer.trainable = False
# Receive the images as inputs.
#inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")

input ='/content/1.png'
input = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(input,target_size=(299,299,3))

BATCH_SIZE = 1
NUM_BOXES = 5
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 3
CROP_SIZE = (24, 24)


boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4))
box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES,), minval=0,
maxval=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32)
output = tf.image.crop_and_resize(input, boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE)
xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(output)
plt.imshow(xception_input/255.)
```

I want to display 5 boxes of each image as written in code. However I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=299x299 at 0x7F1DF6044F10>)
with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>) to a Tensor.
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Ok , I have updated my question with full error message.

Comment: with error message all problem is clear - and I see you already get answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img) the image is loaded in a PIL format. You'll have to convert that to a numpy array before getting the prediction:

```
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path)
input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.
predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
```